# Actualizar datos en un winform desde una Base de datos

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo una aplicacion winforms, la cual dibuja unos controles dentro de un panel, obteniendo algunos datos desde una base de datos, y ejecutandose en un ciclo while sin fin con un tiempo de 5 segundos entre cada consulta.
el formulario se dibuja correctamente, y los datos tambien concuerdan con los de la base de datos.
el problema, es que el cliclo que se ejecuta infinitamente, no refresca los datos cuando cambia el valor en la base de datos. 
si por ejemplo detengo la aplicacion, y la vuelvo a iniciar, los datos se muestran correctamente tal como estan en la base de datos.
aca esta mi codigo del formulario.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (1 == 1)
        {
            int iContador = 0;
            CA_DispensadorRepository dispensadorRepo = new CA_DispensadorRepository();
            List<CA_Dispensador> lstDispensador = dispensadorRepo.GetAll();
            if (lstDispensador != null && lstDispensador.Count > 0)
            {

                foreach (CA_Dispensador dispensador in lstDispensador)
                {
                    Application.DoEvents();

                    iContador++;
                    if (iContador <= 5)
                    {
                        GroupBox MiGroupBox = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
                        MiGroupBox.Name = dispensador.DirecionHexa.Trim().ToUpper();

                        Label AbiertoLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
                        if (dispensador.Abierto)
                        {
                            AbiertoLabel.Text = "Abierto SI";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            AbiertoLabel.Text = "Abierto NO";
                        }
                        AbiertoLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 17);
                        AbiertoLabel.AutoSize = true;
                        AbiertoLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(17, 20);
                        AbiertoLabel.Name = "Abierto";
                        AbiertoLabel.TabIndex = 0;

                        MiGroupBox.Controls.Add(AbiertoLabel);

                        int Columna = 12 * (iContador * 6);
                        MiGroupBox.Location = new Point(12, Columna);
                        MiGroupBox.SuspendLayout();
                        MiGroupBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 71);
                        MiGroupBox.TabIndex = 0;
                        MiGroupBox.TabStop = false;

                        panel1.Controls.Add(MiGroupBox);
                        Application.DoEvents();

                    }
                    Application.DoEvents();

                }
            }
            Application.DoEvents();

            Thread.Sleep(5000);

        }

    }
```

alguna idea de porque la aplicacion se queda "congelada"??
Saludos y gracias por vuestro tiempo

Comment: donde cargas tus datos? falta informacion, pero obviamente nunca se refrescan tus datos.. y no es una buena idea esto... porque no usas un timer que refresque cada 5 segundos, en lugar de usar un ciclo infinito?

Comment: Me parece raro que cada iteración crea un nuevo control que se agrega al formulario en vez de poner al día los existentes. ¿Seguro no estás acumulando una infinidad de controles que se tapan uno al otro, dando la impresión que no estás poniendo los datos al día?

Comment: hola gbianchi, los datos no son el problema, como comentaba al comienzo del post, los datos los obtendo desde y los tengo disponibles dentro del ciclo foreach. mi problema, es que no se refrescan si es que cambian. lo del timer tambien lo probe, pero con ese metodo no se muestra nada, ya que al parecer el proceso que llama al timer no reconoce los objetos creados dentro del timer

Comment: hola sstan, puede ser, en ese caso, como destruyo los objetos una vez que termina el ciclo?

Comment: Te aconsejo encarecidamente que uses un timer en lugar de un bucle infinito. Un bucle infinito tiende a dar problemas,como por ejemplo ocupar el hilo principar evitando el refresco de controles, lo que veo que has solucionado con `Application.DoEvents`, pero esto es tambien problematico y esta desaconsejado. Los timers estan precisamente para esto.

Answer (score 0):

a lo que veo es que cada que entra al ciclo creas un groupbox y dentro de este los controles, esto en cada vuelta, no es que no refresque, si no que pones un groupbox sobre otro, para que esto no suceda debes hacer una de 2 cosas, eliminar el groupbox con todo y controles y crearlos de nuevo o verificar si un control ya existe, no lo creas solo le asignas el valor. Y como te recomiendan, intenta usar un timer en lugar de ciclo infinito.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Segun la documentacion de [`Thread.Sleep()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Suspende el hilo actual un tiempo especificado

Por cada iteracion del `while`, estas suspendiendo el hilo de la vista de tu formulario lo que causa que la aplicación *"se frise"*.

Intenta ejecutando el `while` en otro hilo para que pause el hilo nuevo y no el hilo de la vista:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.StartNew(()=>{
      while(true)
      {
         // tu codigo
      }
    });
}
```

Ahora bien, tendrás problemas porque no puedes modificar controles del formulario en otro hilo que no sea en el hilo de la vista. Asi que siempre que vayas modificar un control, ya sea por ejemplo cambiar la texto de un Label o ocultar un control, tienes que utilizar el metodo `Invoke`. Por ejemplo:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.StartNew(()=>{
      while (1 == 1)
        {
            //...
            if (lstDispensador != null && lstDispensador.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (CA_Dispensador dispensador in lstDispensador)
                {
                    //...
                    if (iContador <= 5)
                    {
                        //...

                        if (dispensador.Abierto)
                        {
                            // el metodo invoke nos evita el error de modificar un control en otro hilo
                            AbiertoLabel.Invoke(()=>{
                                AbiertoLabel.Text = "Abierto SI";
                            })
                        }
            //...
    });
}
```